# C# access unmanaged array using Memory<T> or ArraySegment<T>?

Tags: c#, unmanaged-memory

With the introduction of `Memory`, `Span` and `ArraySegment` in C# 7.2, I was wondering if I could represent an unmanaged array as an enumerable object, that lives on the heap.

This latter requirement rules out `Span`, which basically implemented exactly what I wanted: e.g.

```
unsafe { bytes = new Span<byte>((byte*)ptr + (index * Width), Width);
```

Is it possible to do the same with `ArraySegment` or `Memory`? Their constructors only accept `byte[]`, maybe there some way to trick C# into passing a `byte*` instead of `byte[]`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this with a `Span` or `Memory`? You can `Marshal.GlobalHAlloc` and get an `IntPtr` to work with a set of unmanaged memory directly. You may be able to somehow translate that into a `byte[]` that can be passed into those objects. Are you wanting to create a new memory block to work on, or are you trying to access another process memory block?

Comment: I'm using SkiaSharp to load images which I iterate over byte by byte. Currently I use a provided property which copies the data as `byte[]` to work with, but Skia also provides a native pointer to the unmanaged memory, which I want to explore because it saves me a memory copy.

Comment: @RonBeyer `Memory<byte>` is actually *perfect* for this...

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree now that I understand what the use case was, but I was unaware of the custom `MemoryManager<T>`, thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes for `Memory<T>`, but you need to create your own `MemoryManager<T>`. Don't worry - this isn't as scary as it sounds - [here's one I wrote earlier...](https://github.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/blob/master/src/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/UnsafeMemory.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// A MemoryManager over a raw pointer
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>The pointer is assumed to be fully unmanaged, or externally pinned - no attempt will be made to pin this data</remarks>
public sealed unsafe class UnmanagedMemoryManager<T> : MemoryManager<T>
    where T : unmanaged
{
    private readonly T* _pointer;
    private readonly int _length;

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new UnmanagedMemoryManager instance at the given pointer and size
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>It is assumed that the span provided is already unmanaged or externally pinned</remarks>
    public UnmanagedMemoryManager(Span<T> span)
    {
        fixed (T* ptr = &MemoryMarshal.GetReference(span))
        {
            _pointer = ptr;
            _length = span.Length;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new UnmanagedMemoryManager instance at the given pointer and size
    /// </summary>
    public UnmanagedMemoryManager(T* pointer, int length)
    {
        if (length < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(length));
        _pointer = pointer;
        _length = length;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Obtains a span that represents the region
    /// </summary>
    public override Span<T> GetSpan() => new Span<T>(_pointer, _length);

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides access to a pointer that represents the data (note: no actual pin occurs)
    /// </summary>
    public override MemoryHandle Pin(int elementIndex = 0)
    {
        if (elementIndex < 0 || elementIndex >= _length)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(elementIndex));
        return new MemoryHandle(_pointer + elementIndex);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Has no effect
    /// </summary>
    public override void Unpin() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Releases all resources associated with this object
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) { }
}
```

Now you can use:

```
var mgr = new UnmanagedMemoryManager((byte*)ptr + (index * Width), Width);
Memory<byte> memory = mgr.Memory;
```

and `memory` can be stored on the heap.

However, to minimize allocations you probably want to create a *single* `UnmanagedMemoryManager<byte>` that covers the *entire* region - once only - and then use `.Slice(...)` on the `.Memory` that represents the entire region. That way you have a single object and lots of slices  (the slices are structs, not objects).

Note this implementation assumes that you're going to control the lifetime of the memory elsewhere - the `Dispose()` here **does not** attempt to release the memory via `Marshal` etc.

Comment: `UnmanagedMemoryManager` - A legitimate use of a paradox if I've ever seen one.

Comment: @AaronLS it does seem somewhat an oxymoron, I agree

Comment: @AaronLS Maybe it needs a manager _because_ it's "unmanaged"? ;-)

Comment: @MarcGravell This is amazing. Is there anything special I need to do to use this? I get `The type or namespace name 'unmanaged' could not be found`. Already imported `System.Buffers` and `InteropServices`

Comment: I removed the `unmanaged` interface and all the generics and it is now working.

Comment: @RedRidingHood the "unmanaged" constraint requires c# 7.3 IIRC. The buffers and interop bits sound like duplicate "using" directives. Since I didn't include any, I think those are in the bits you added...

Comment: Can you explain how the pinning survives line #28 : https://github.com/mgravell/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/blob/master/src/Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial/UnsafeMemory.cs#L28 ?

Comment: @springy76 look at L21 - read the comment; this code is intended for *already pinned* scenarios, or (and especially) unmanaged memory where pinning just isn't a concern

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks, that was useful insight. Any reason you dont free/dispose pointer in Dispose? And is there some way to constraint constructor that accepts Span to ensure it is unmanaged or pinned one underneath?

Comment: @KreonZZ I simply didn't assume I was taking ownership, or indeed anything about how it was allocated. If you want to do that, sure - but there are many ways to get a pointer and they aren't all Marshal.AllocHGlobal (or whatever the method is called). And "no" to the second point. The span doesn't know.

Comment: Ah, I see, you used your wrapper as a `memoryview` into unmanaged Interior Pointer rather than actual managed abstraction wrapper, got it. Guess I can repurpose it myself for the latter, hopefully no feet will be shot!

Comment: @KreonZZ meh, feet are somewhat overrated. Have fun!

Comment: @MarcGravell by the way is there an error in your example? `new UnmanagedMemoryManager((byte*)ptr + (index * Width), Width);`Width should be the size of an element (in case of byte = 1) so you multiple it by index to get offset but then you also supply Width as a length, which is weird.

Comment: @KreonZZ that part was taken from the original question.

Comment: This looks really promising, but I need an ArraySegment (for browser-wasm interop), not a Memory. I've tried calling `TryGetArray`, but get the error `MemoryManager<byte>.TryGetArray(out ArraySegment<byte>)' is inaccessible due to its protection level`. Any ideas?

Comment: @curiousdannii MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray - if it returns false, you can use a leased array (ArrayPool-T.Shared), rent, copy, use, return