# Avoiding Span<T>.ToArray() in an async method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, memory-management

Upgraded some code to be asynchronous and realized that `Span<T>` cannot be used in an `async` method.

Invoking `Span<T>.ToArray()` fixes the issue at the cost of allocating every single time.

Can you suggest a pattern on how to avoid allocating in this case?

```
using ISO9660.Logical;

namespace ISO9660.Physical;

public static class DiscExtensions
{
    public static async Task ReadFileRawAsync(this Disc disc, IsoFileSystemEntryFile file, Stream stream)
    {
        await ReadFileAsync(disc, file, stream, ReadFileRaw);
    }

    public static async Task ReadFileUserAsync(this Disc disc, IsoFileSystemEntryFile file, Stream stream)
    {
        await ReadFileAsync(disc, file, stream, ReadFileUser);
    }

    private static async Task ReadFileAsync(Disc disc, IsoFileSystemEntryFile file, Stream stream, ReadFileHandler handler)
    {
        int position = (int)file.Position;

        Track track = disc.Tracks.FirstOrDefault(s => position >= s.Position)
                      ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to determine track for file.");

        int sectors = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)file.Length / track.Sector.GetUserDataLength());

        for (int i = position; i < position + sectors; i++)
        {
            ISector sector = await track.ReadSectorAsync(i);

            byte[] array = handler(file, stream, sector).ToArray(); // sucks

            await stream.WriteAsync(array);
        }
    }

    private static Span<byte> ReadFileRaw(IsoFileSystemEntryFile file, Stream stream, ISector sector)
    {
        Span<byte> data = sector.GetData();

        int size = data.Length;

        Span<byte> span = data[..size];

        return span;
    }

    private static Span<byte> ReadFileUser(IsoFileSystemEntryFile file, Stream stream, ISector sector)
    {
        Span<byte> data = sector.GetUserData();

        int size = (int)Math.Min(Math.Max(file.Length - stream.Length, 0), data.Length);

        Span<byte> span = data[..size];

        return span;
    }

    private delegate Span<byte> ReadFileHandler(IsoFileSystemEntryFile file, Stream stream, ISector sector);
}
```

ISector interface:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshalling;

namespace ISO9660.Physical;

public interface ISector
{
    int Length { get; }

    Span<byte> GetData();

    Span<byte> GetUserData();

    int GetUserDataLength();

    public static Span<byte> GetSpan<T>(scoped ref T sector, int start, int length)
        where T : struct, ISector
    {
        var span = MemoryMarshal.CreateSpan(ref sector, 1);

        var bytes = MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(span);

        var slice = bytes.Slice(start, length);

        return slice;
    }
    
    public static ISector Read<T>(Stream stream)
        where T : struct, ISector
    {
        var size = Unsafe.SizeOf<T>();

        Span<byte> span = stackalloc byte[size];

        stream.ReadExactly(span);

        var read = MemoryMarshal.Read<T>(span);

        return read;
    }

    public static async Task<ISector> ReadAsync<T>(Stream stream)
        where T : struct, ISector
    {
        var buffer = new byte[Unsafe.SizeOf<T>()];

        await stream.ReadExactlyAsync(buffer);

        var sector = MemoryMarshal.Read<T>(buffer);

        return sector;
    }
}
```

ISector implementation example:

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;

namespace ISO9660.Physical;

public unsafe struct SectorRawMode1 : ISector
{
    private const int UserDataLength = 2048;

    private const int UserDataPosition = 16;

    [UsedImplicitly]
    public fixed byte Sync[12];

    [UsedImplicitly]
    public fixed byte Header[4];

    [UsedImplicitly]
    public fixed byte UserData[UserDataLength];

    [UsedImplicitly]
    public fixed byte Edc[4];

    [UsedImplicitly]
    public fixed byte Intermediate[8];

    [UsedImplicitly]
    public fixed byte PParity[172];

    [UsedImplicitly]
    public fixed byte QParity[104];

    public readonly int Length => 2352;

    public Span<byte> GetData()
    {
        return ISector.GetSpan(ref this, 0, Length);
    }

    public Span<byte> GetUserData()
    {
        return ISector.GetSpan(ref this, UserDataPosition, UserDataLength);
    }

    public readonly int GetUserDataLength()
    {
        return UserDataLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please replace all of the `var` keywords with their actual compile-time static types.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not passing a `CancellationToken`?

Comment: `var position = (int)file.Position;` <-- ISO 9660 allows volumes up to 8TB in length, but your code assumes a 32-bit (4GB) limit. You should be using `Int64` here.

Comment: What is `ReadFileHandler`?

Comment: @Dai Going to pass cancellation token, trying to figure out that problem first. Well... position comes from *location of extent* in a directory record, which is is encoded as 7.3.3 in ECMA-130, i.e. a 32-bit unsigned integer. Not sure how you can get 8TB from that. `ReadFileHandler` is here to separate the logic of computing the span, previously, it was a single method using a bool parameter and it felt weird.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57229123/how-to-use-spanbyte-in-async-method

Comment: What are the different `ISector` implementations, and how do they return a `Span<Byte>`?

Comment: Can you upload a (buildable) example to DotNetFiddle or similar? I think the problem here is that this probably isn't an appropriate use of `Span`: a `Span<Byte>` is a view over mutable managed or native memory (which will have its own lifetime too) - I assume you're trying to accomplish some kind of _zero-copy_ way of reading from a disc?

Comment: @Allanckw sure but you just deport the problem, `WriteAsync` will have to be `await` and same problem will appear in local method as it must be made async.

Comment: @Dai, pasted the ISector interface and an implementation example. Pasting a compilable 'snippet' is going to be difficult, there is a lot more involved in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Span<T>` to `Memory<T>` and push the change upwards. `Memory<T>` is analogous to `Span<T>` for async (in practice). The idea is unlike a `Span`, a `Memory` can live on the heap (and thus can't refer to a `stackalloc`).

There is no `MemoryMarshal.CreateMemory` so you have to do it the old fashioned way: pin, take address, and construct a `Memory` form a pointer. Example how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52191681/14768 Note that the MemoryManager allocation is far smaller than the buffer allocation and you don't need to copy.

Be very careful how you write your code; this MemoryManager's constructor does indeed take a `Span` that is the entire `ISector`, and it will live across `async` calls; but if you fail to dispose it, memory leak. Also, if the `ISector` came from the stack rather than the heap, that's on you and you will trash stack.