Dispose(bool) for a managed wrapper, is it native or managed in the end?
In the dispose pattern documentation, this is suggested on how to dispose object:
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (_disposed)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (disposing)
    {
        // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
    }

    // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
    // TODO: set large fields to null.

    _disposed = true;
}

Now, suppose I have a managed wrapper that allocates aligned unmanaged memory:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Whatever.Extensions;

namespace XYZ.Extensions;

public sealed class NativeMemory<T> : DisposableAsync where T : unmanaged
{
    public unsafe NativeMemory(uint count, uint alignment = 1)
    {
        ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfZero(alignment);

        Length = count * (uint)sizeof(T);

        Pointer = (nint)NativeMemory.AlignedAlloc(Length, alignment);

        Manager = new NativeMemoryManager<T>((T*)Pointer, (int)Length);

        Manager.Memory.Span.Clear();
    }

    public NativeMemoryManager<T> Manager { get; }

    public uint Length { get; }

    public nint Pointer { get; }

    protected override ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
    {
        DisposeNative();

        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected override void DisposeNative()
    {
        DisposePointer();
    }

    private unsafe void DisposePointer()
    {
        NativeMemory.AlignedFree(Pointer.ToPointer());
    }
}

Memory manager:
using System.Buffers;

namespace ISO9660.Extensions;

public sealed unsafe class NativeMemoryManager<T>(T* pointer, int length)
    : MemoryManager<T> where T : unmanaged
{
    private T* Pointer { get; } = pointer;

    private int Length { get; } = length;

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // NOP
    }

    public override Span<T> GetSpan()
    {
        return new Span<T>(Pointer, Length);
    }

    public override MemoryHandle Pin(int elementIndex = 0)
    {
        ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfNegative(elementIndex);

        ArgumentOutOfRangeException.ThrowIfGreaterThanOrEqual(elementIndex, Length);

        return new MemoryHandle(Pointer + elementIndex);
    }

    public override void Unpin()
    {
        // NOP
    }
}

Disposable helper:
using System;

#nullable disable
namespace Whatever.Extensions
{
  public abstract class Disposable : IDisposable
  {
    protected bool IsDisposed { get; set; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      this.Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize((object) this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (this.IsDisposed)
        return;
      this.DisposeNative();
      if (disposing)
        this.DisposeManaged();
      this.IsDisposed = true;
    }

    protected virtual void DisposeManaged() { }

    protected virtual void DisposeNative() { }

    ~Disposable() => this.Dispose(false);
  }
}

DisposableAsync helper:
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

#nullable enable
namespace Whatever.Extensions
{
  public abstract class DisposableAsync : Disposable, IAsyncDisposable
  {
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
      DisposableAsync disposableAsync = this;
      await disposableAsync.DisposeAsyncCore().ConfigureAwait(false);
      GC.SuppressFinalize((object) disposableAsync);
    }

    protected virtual async ValueTask DisposeAsyncCore()
    {
      await new ValueTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
  }
}

Now things are ambiguous... Is that a managed or unmanaged thing to dispose of?
Question:
When disposing NativeMemory<T>, should I consider it as managed or unmanaged?

@Progman Added the relevant helpers.

Are you asking what to do when you reference a NativeMemory<T> object and want to dispose it or are you talking about when inside the NativeMemory<T> and you want to dispose any managed/unmanaged resources?

@Progman I am talking about disposing NativeMemory<T> inside Dispose(bool), should it be disposed inside if (disposing) (i.e. managed) or outside (i.e. native)?

What does NativeMemoryManager do, where is its definition? And why does the dispose need to be async?

It's a custom MemoryManager like https://stackoverflow.com/a/52191681/361899, just implemented async dispose on all these types.

I've added its definition so there's no confusion, basically it allows to use memory/span in async scenarios.

NativeMemory<T> is managed object, owning the unmanaged resources. So

NativeMemory<T> instances should be disposed in the managed disposal branch (when disposing==true)
Inside the NativeMemory<T>.Dispose() implementation we need free unmanaged resources, owned by this instance of the NativeMemory<T> in the unmanaged disposal branch (when disposing==false). (so, the NativeMemory.AlignedFree should be in the disposing==false branch).

P.S. I'm a little bit confused about the NativeMemoryManager<T> field. Does it owns the unmanaged memory or not? If the real owner is the NativeMemoryManager<T>, then the answer should be different.
P.P.S. You may consider to implement a wrapper inherited from the SafeHandle or one of its standard inheritors. SafeHandle can give you more reliable (optionally owning) managed wrapper for the unmanaged resources.

Added the definition of memory manager, I would say it does not own memory. Not sure what you mean by using a safe handle in this case.

From the given implementation I would say that NativeMemoryManager<T> does not own the unmanaged resource (it but just provides a convenient interface for it), so the answer is valid. At the same time it implements the IMemoryOwner<T> interface (as does the base class), so the current non-owning implementation may break some contract (and definitely breaks semantics). But I can't decide for myself which way to change the code will is the best here.
